# Compile time specialize against function pointer references for avoiding -Waddress

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, c++17, metaprogramming

I'm encountering the following issue with GCC (tested with v6.4 it's the same behavior on the current trunk) which can be reduced to the following minimalistic example:

Further we look at callable objects such as classes that implement `operator()` and `operator bool` and function pointers such as `void(*)()` and function references `void(&)()`.

Following questions might be relevant to be read in advance:

- [Difference between void(*)() and void(&)() in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30560947/difference-between-void-and-void-in-c)
- [Function pointer vs Function reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19200513/function-pointer-vs-function-reference)

I'm trying to implement a conditional invoke which checks before a callable is invoked whether its conversion to `bool` is `true` before invoking it:

```
/// g++-6.4 -O3 -std=c++17 -Wall

#include <functional>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename O>
void safe_invoke(O&& fn) {
  if (fn) {
    std::invoke(std::forward<O>(fn));
  }
}

void somefn() { }

int main() {
    safe_invoke(somefn);
    return 0;
}
```

Will yield a warning when using GCC and -Wall

```
In instantiation of 'void safe_invoke(O&&) [with O = void (&)()]':
  warning: the compiler can assume that the address of 'fn' will always evaluate to 'true' [-Waddress]
    if (fn) {
    ^~
```

As indicated by the warning GCC uses `void(&)()` as the correct reference type of the callable type `O`. My approach in dealing with this warning was that I want to get completely rid of the `bool(callable)` check for a function references which can never be null by specializing those with a specific trait:

```
/// g++-6.4 -O3 -std=c++17 -Wall -Werror
/// https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/2TCaHq

#include <functional>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
struct invoke_trait {
  template <typename O>
  static void invoke(O&& fn) {
    if (fn) {
      std::invoke(std::forward<T>(fn));
    }
  }
};

template <typename Ret, typename... Args>
struct invoke_trait<Ret (*)(Args...)> {
  template <typename O>
  static void invoke(O&& fn) {
    if (fn) {
      std::invoke(std::forward<O>(fn));
    }
  }
};

template <typename Ret, typename... Args>
struct invoke_trait<Ret (&)(Args...)> {
  template <typename O>
  static void invoke(O&& fn) {
    std::invoke(std::forward<O>(fn));
  }
};

template <typename O>
void safe_invoke(O&& fn) {
  using trait_t = invoke_trait<std::decay_t<O>>;
  trait_t::invoke(std::forward<O>(fn));
}

void test() {
}

int main() {
  // No compile error as expected:
  {
    using fn_t = void (*)();
    fn_t fn = nullptr;

    safe_invoke(fn);
  }

  // the compiler can assume that the address of 'fn' will always evaluate
  // to 'true' [-Werror=address]
  {
    safe_invoke(test);
  }

  // the compiler can assume that the address of 'fn' will always evaluate
  // to 'true' [-Werror=address]
  {
    using fn_ref_t = void (&)();
    fn_ref_t fn_ref = test;

    safe_invoke(fn_ref);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

**https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/3QAKpf**

**Sadly GCC fails here and always uses the specialization for `Ret (*)(Args...)`. Is there an issue with my code which prevents the correct specialization to `Ret (&)(Args...)` or can this specialization be done differently?**
Additionally is there a different way to prevent the GCC warning without suppressing it explicitly (although this might not be the optimal solution)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
std::decay_t<O>
```

This converts function references to function pointers.

Replace decay with a combination of remove reference and remove CV.  Then specialize on `F(Args...)` and `F(*)(Args...)` instead of `F(&)(Args...)` and `F(*)(Args...)`.

```
template <typename Ret, typename... Args>
struct invoke_trait<Ret (*)(Args...)> {
  template <typename O>
  static void invoke(O&& fn) {
    if (fn) {
      std::invoke(std::forward<O>(fn));
    }
  }
};

template <typename Ret, typename... Args>
struct invoke_trait<Ret(Args...)> {
  template <typename O>
  static void invoke(O&& fn) {
    std::invoke(std::forward<O>(fn));
  }
};

template <typename O>
void safe_invoke(O&& fn) {
  using trait_t = invoke_trait<std::remove_cv_t<std::remove_reference_t<O>>>;
  trait_t::invoke(std::forward<O>(fn));
}
```

That should work, up to typos.

Comment: `using trait_t = invoke_trait<std::remove_reference_t<std::remove_cv_t<O>>>;` doesn't fix the issue here, but good catch of you that `decay` converts the function reference to a pointer. Probably the issue is also that I've used `Ret (&)(Args...)` instead of `Ret (Args...)`,

Comment: @Timo What, are you saying that `int(&)(int, int)` passed to `std::remove_reference_t` returns `int(*)(int, int)`?  Check again.

Comment: @DenisBlank No, remove reference first, then remove cv.

Comment: Good catch. I corrected that and also marked your answer as the solution because you additionally spotted the issue with the `Ret(Args...)`. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont my bad, I didn't notice that the compiler error changed. The generalized trait threw the warning instead of the pointer trait.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem lies in the `safe_invoke` function:

```
template <typename O>
void safe_invoke(O&& fn) {
  using trait_t = invoke_trait<std::decay_t<O>>;
  trait_t::invoke(std::forward<O>(fn));
}
```

At this point `O` might be a function reference, but `std::decay_t<O>` will decay it to a function **pointer**. To quote [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/decay) on this:

> Otherwise, if T is a function type F or a reference thereto, the member typedef type is std::add_pointer::type.

The decayed type will therefore always choose the pointer trait.

Maybe use

```
using trait_t = invoke_trait<std::remove_cv_t<O>>;
```

instead.